Can PPL hours be from multiple countries (Europe, UK)?
If you have some PPL hours from various European countries, such as France, Spain, Portugal, Greece - do these count towards the minimum 40 hours to take the PPL GST in the UK?

Great question, aviation regulations post-brexit are a complete mess. Really hard to find the actual answer.

@Jamiec Why do the CAA not make this information clearer I wonder.

This question likely falls under the domain of "interpretation of regulations spaghetti." Find a flight training outfit in your area and ask.

@mins Just like US law more like!

If you have PPL hours from countries such as the ones you mentioned they can count for the minimum 40 hours you need for the PPL GST test in the UK as long as they were completed under the standards of an ICAO-compliant training program. The CAA recognizes flight training from ICAO members including all the countries you mentioned. There are some additional requirements you will need to meet such as a Valid UK medical certificate class 1(Or 2 depending on your plans for future flight operations) and some other requirements you can find in my listed sources.
SOUCES:

How to validate your ICAO third country license
Private pilot license for airplanes
Third Country License conversion requirements from 1 January 2023.


@Jamiec is this correct? Asking you as I know you are close to the CAA..

@Cloud I'm about as far from the CAA as a person could be. As I've explained to you before :) All 3 of those links are to pages on the UK CAA website, so that's about as authoritative as you can get for UK Aviation regulation.
